# How to set up a jQuery UI progress bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, jquery-ui-progressbar

I'm trying to display a progress bar while the images on my page load (there are 95). I can get the progress bar to display but only in

```
$(document).ready() { ... }
```

Is this right?

And what is the best method for determining the % of images that are / are not loaded? I will pass this value into a function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateLoaded(val) {
        $('#progressBar').progressbar({
            value: val
        });
    }
    updateLoaded(0);                                   // initial value

    $('ul#sold img').addClass('soldImg');
    var total = $('.soldImg').size();
    var complete = 0;

    $('.soldImg').load(function() {
        complete++;
        updateLoaded((complete / total) * 100);        // % done
    }
});
```

Should I use:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

instead of the .ready() function?

Comment: The second usage is the same thing as the first one (doc.ready)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be in any function at all, just like this:

```
function updateLoaded(val) {
    $('#progressBar').progressbar({
        value: val
    });
}
updateLoaded(0);                                   // initial value

$('ul#sold img').addClass('soldImg');
var total = $('.soldImg').size();
var complete = 0;

$('.soldImg').load(function() {
    complete++;
    updateLoaded((complete / total) * 100);        // % done
}
```